# Why are asp.net charts showing equal values when values are numerically different?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

When charting data in ASP.NET, my chart visually represents equal data values where the data values are clearly different:

This is the chart which I am getting and here is my code:
[image]

```
DataTable dt = GetChartData();

double sum = 0;
string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
double[] y = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
      sum =  Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][1]);
      y[i] = sum;
      Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = x[i];
}

Chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;

// Chart1.DataSource = x;
Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
Chart1.Titles.Add("NewTitle");
Chart1.Titles["NewTitle"].Text = "Rainfall Trend";
List<double> yValues = new List<double>(y);
List<string> xValues = new List<string>(x);
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
```

Why is the chart representing equal values when there aren't any?

Comment: But as per the image attached, I could see different Y values 1996,7,8 etc. What is the exact issue?

Comment: As Anand noted the values go from 1996 to 1999. They will, of course __look__ the same for columns of a few hundred pixels.  Also: `List<double> yValues = new List<double>(y);
List<string> xValues = new List<string>(x);
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);` makes me wonder about when the actual data come in..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to summarize the problem. I also edited your post to make it more of a question so that others can more clearly understand it. Good luck!

Comment: Also try to use values that are significantly different. For testing, hard code in values like 900, 1990, 3507, etc. These should make it clearer whether or not the bars are actually all showing equal or similar heights.